# LINQ to SQL ObjectDisposedException on entity that never asked for

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I have this strange behavior. Im Loading some entities in a List<> and append to a grid.
When double click the grid i take the row cast to the entity and append to a property.

I have changed some things in my database and code and now i get this exception while i never wanted to check something on this Entity Reference.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your explanation is hard to follow. Posting code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen to me when I try to access a property that isn't one of the columns on the database table that the entity is derived from.

For example, maybe your database has a table `Vehicle` with columns `Id`, `Year`, `Make`, `Model`, and `EngineId`. The LinqToSql entity will have a property for each column, but it also adds a property called `Engine`, which holds an `Engine` entity.

If you convert your `Vehicle` data to a `List<Vehicle>` then try to access some property on the `Engine`, you will get an `ObjectDisposedException` unless your `DataContext` is still active.

So, if you need, say, `Vehicle.Engine.CylinderCount` after you're done with your `DataContext`, you'll need to build a custom object that flattens your data so that you only need one "dot" to get to the data you need.

You can write a `ViewModel` class to easily accomplish this. For example:

```
public class VehicleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int EngineId { get; set; }
    public int CylinderCount { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you write your LinqToSql query to populate a `List<VehicleViewModel>` instead of a `List<Vehicle>`, you should stop getting an `ObjectDisposedException` when you try to access the `CylinderCount`.